# Localhost not displaying same components as in the server

Tags: php, configuration, web, localhost, wamp

Okay so a few days ago I had my localhost running off of Wamp to where the files I was working on were connected to my server (through bitbucket to where I can use git in aptana) and everything was working fine (whatever displayed on my localhost off of Wamp server displayed on my bluehost server of course when everything was up to date).

I had to re-install Wamp and I cloned my project again from bitbuckit into my www directory (through aptana) to where my localhost would be connected to my server again and also imported the database to where the setup should be exactly as on the server.

This time when I go to my localhost on my computer to display the components/webpages it doesn't display everything. It only displays the background of my pages and components being used on all across the entire site.

Since everything on the localhost is exactly the same as server (code and database) it should display like it does on the server.

What could be causing this?

Are there configurations in Wamp that could be causing components to not display?

I have re-installed Wamp multiple times as well as trying this on Xampp and the same thing is happening.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe your application has configuration values set to an absolute path of the SERVER and not your LOCAL system?

Comment: It shouldn't be though before my first re-install of Wamp it was working fine on my LOCAL system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the Wamp/Xampp version I was installing (which were the new versions) had php versions which wasn't compatible with the php version that is off of bluehost server (which is currently at 5.2.17).

So I installed Xampp version 1.7.1 (which supports php version 5.2.8).

And now my local is working exactly as my server...EVERYTHING is displaying as it should!