# Website doesn't function the same way as it does on my localhost (wamp) server

Tags: php, html

First off, I ran into this issue when transferring all of my files from my localhost (wamp server) to my web server via FileZilla. Everything works great on my test server but when looking at it on my domain it doesn't appear the same nor does it function the same.

I tried to research this issue before asking and closest thing I found was this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369411/localhost-not-displaying-same-components-as-in-the-server) which doesn't help me with my specific problem.

---

What my test servers looks like and how  the website *should* function on the web-server:

- Show the sign-up and sign-in buttons on the navigation bar.
- Show the proper content accordingly from the action page.

What my website is doing when uploading it to the web-server:

- Shows the `sign-up` & `sign-in` buttons when navigating to the website ([www.heartfx.org/test](http://www.heartfx.org/test))
- Does not display proper content like my *localhost server* does with the [action page](http://pastebin.com/0y59UFBT).

So instead of a user being linked to an external page for each function like `login.php, register.php, forgot_password.php` etc... they are linked to a single page like `http://www.heartfx.org/action.php?action=register_account` where I then `$_get['action']` and display each *"page"*.

The code on my web-server for some reason doesn't display those *"pages"* but only the navigation bar on top of the page and nothing under it.

---

How `/action.php?action=sign_in` should look(as it does on local server):

[image]

How `/action.php?action=sign_in` looks on the web-server:

[image]

---

*Another thing to mention*: I also have this question being posted / answered on, on another community where someone had me run the following line down the code until I ran into a spot where the *line number* didn't echo;

`echo '<br>Line: ' .__LINE__; die;`

The line number `echo`'d completely fine until I placed the line of code underneath a `showHeader('');` function in my *[action.php page](http://pastebin.com/0y59UFBT)*. When placing the line of code underneath a `showHeader('');` function it did not echo the line number as it should with that statement.

We figured it was due to something with the `showHeader('');` function which is being included in `common.inc.php` but cannot figure out what is wrong with the function that is causing it to not display each *"page"*. The code on the web-server is exactly the same it is on the localhost server other then database credentials.

**UPDATE:** So after sitting idle at an action page (specifically I was at [/action.php?action=register_account](http://www.heartfx.org/test/action.php?action=register_account)) for about *10 minutes* and refreshing the page the module appeared as it should've when first loading the page. When roaming around the page for a bit and *refreshing a 2nd time* it AGAIN goes blank and run into the same issue.

Comment: do you have any errors in the log?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Are all references relative? eg /style.css and not http:www...

Comment: @RafaelShkembi On top of my _action.php_ page I have set: `error_reporting(-1);ini_set('display_errors', 'true');` and it does not display any errors to me. Also the *error_log* file in my web-server is completely empty.

Comment: @ThorstenC Yes, everything linked in my `<head>` tags are linked as /style.css not external links (other then jQuery and importing fonts from google fonts)

Comment: i didn't see any error on the page.. Show us the php code that makes the get request

Comment: @RafaelShkembi The `$_get` request is at the top of my [action.php page](http://pastebin.com/0y59UFBT), specifically line #5.

Comment: If you open your browsers dev tools (usually F12), and go to network tab, refresh the page. Are there any 404 errors? Maybe `/action.php` is an OK mapping on your localhost, but perhaps the config is different on your server, and it can't load a resource that should be there

Comment: @AlexSzabó Sorry, I am not sure what I am looking for here but on my web-server I have refreshed the page with *network tab* up and [did not get any sort of errors](https://puu.sh/sycfp/817bb696f4.png).

Comment: well, actually [your url](http://www.heartfx.org/test/action.php?action=sign_in) works good, doesn't it? or, what's the url of your server?

Comment: @GiuServ Very weird, when clicking on your link just now, it seemed to work but after refreshing the page a few times, it went back to the issue I had earlier (Not displaying anything accordingly to what `action=`) :O

Comment: @GiuServ For some reason when sitting at the site for an extended period of time, eventually the content according to what `$action =` but after refreshing the page and going the homepage and returning to an `$action=` page it shows up blank again.

Comment: Half of the HTML body is missing when I do view-source [here](http://www.heartfx.org/test/action.php?action=sign_in).

Comment: @MCEmperor For some reason it's not even displaying the code I have for the action page: `if ($action == 'sign_in') {` which it should be if `action=sign_in` in the url. Also the reason it may seem incomplete is because I have a php script running in between those tags as it [shows here](http://pastebin.com/jcSuZ04c).

Comment: If you use .htaccess check it again. I had problems month ago after transferred files from Wamp (Win 8.1) to Ubuntu server. After a week of checking scripts and kicking my head against the wall it was regex issue in RewriteRule(s) which works slightly different between those Systems. So almost all my paths were wrong (css/js/media).

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 I don't use `.htaccess` as I don't think I have access to change it regarding my permissions given from my webhosting provider. As I said though, I haven't ever touched my `.htaccess` file before.

Comment: Try to check if the config (php.ini) is the same, and if the `$_SERVER` variables, like `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` or `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, output the same values.

Comment: Can you post the php code of that page?

Comment: @GiuServ Sure, here is [common.inc.php](http://pastebin.com/dGcSEs4y) file where mainly *all* of my functions are and here is [action.php file](http://pastebin.com/eY307HxT) where I `$_get` the action from the url & use that to display certain content depending on what `$action=`. Not sure if you need it but here is my [index.php file](http://pastebin.com/FhiKJc5c) as well!

Comment: In **common.inc.php**, on line **52** — what happens if you set `error_reporting` to `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: @MCEmperor Nothing changes really. Again my website happened to be working for a moment but when trying to refresh the page once, it goes back blank. That specific `error_reporting(0);` was for displaying my teamspeak server information *(users connected, channels, etc)*.

Comment: @cscodismith So... *Sometimes* the input fields are shown, but sometimes not?

Comment: @MCEmperor So if I sit idle at `/action.php` for some time and refresh page - very rarely.. the page actually responds and shows me the content that's intended but after refreshing the page again and 99% of the time visiting the page, usually it displays nothing but the navigation bar. 

Also take a look at the bottom of the original post **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862138/website-doesnt-function-the-same-way-as-it-does-on-my-localhost-wamp-server)**: It explains that there may be something wrong with the `showHeader('')` function but I am just not sure what is causing it.

Comment: the problem should be with your php, but there's incomplete code pasted here. The part relative to the table use for signin in, that is missing when you can't see it, is not defined neither in action.php nor config.php. You should give all your code to try to help you. Look at [the attacched image](http://imgur.com/a/NkmpU) to see what is missing

Answer (score 0):

Finally tracked down what was causing this issue and how to fix it. Inside of the `showHeader('')` that I am calling is another `checkLogin()` function that includes a Teamspeak3 query that displays my teamspeak server. That query for some reason was messing up the rest of my code (including the `action.php` page where I am trying to display everything.

Also would explain why very rarely I seen the page actually work and refreshing it, again made the page blank (other then the navigation bar) because the teamspeak query was still loading - causing the rest of the page not to load.

To fix this I simply removed the query from [common.inc.php](http://pastebin.com/dGcSEs4y) as it is *not* a mandatory function to have on my site. Thanks to everyone that helped me track down the issue.

```
/*       
// Don't report any php errors.
error_reporting(0);

// load framework files
require_once("includes/libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");

// connect to server, authenticate and spawn an object for the virtual server on port xxxx
$ts3_VirtualServer = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://serverquerylogin:ATJ75oPF@63.251.20.99:14012/?server_port=14010&use_offline_as_virtual=1&no_query_clients=1");

// build and display HTML treeview using custom image paths (remote icons will be embedded using data URI sheme)
echo $ts3_VirtualServer->getViewer(new TeamSpeak3_Viewer_Html("includes/images/viewer/", "", "data:image"));

// Report all php errors again.
error_reporting(-1);
*/
```